# Mercurial hg recover ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: version-control, mercurial, recover

I attempted to push to a mercurial repo and got a message that it was waiting for a lock from a co-worker who had already left for the day. This has happened multiple times as for some reason pushes across the vpn don't always get their locks cleaned up. I delete the lock and go to recover the repo but this doesn't go as normal.

```
>hg recover
rolling back interrupted transaction
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.1.1)
** Extensions loaded: eol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 42, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 28, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 69, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 138, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 820, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 600, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 911, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 882, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 817, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 550, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4835, in recover
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 914, in recover
  File "mercurial\transaction.pyo", line 304, in rollback
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a repo over a VPN is a bad idea and can generally lead to corruption during operations where the vpn drops out: see [this bug](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4047).

This was resolved by cloning the repo on the server at the latest successful pushed commit hg clone -r <#>

Then I had to do a fresh clone on my end from the new repository that got cloned. Then I was able to push successfully from the new repo.

Comment: Note `hg clone -r #` only gets # and it's ancestors. If you have other heads they won't be cloned.